# HuggingFace ByteLevelBPETokenizer encoding issue in merge.txt file

Tags: python, encoding, nlp, pytorch, tokenize

I am using HuggingFace ByteLevelBPETokenizer to generate vocabulary for **marathi language**
("आपण हवे ते लेख शोधू शकता")

When I train marathi language data, I end up with such outputs in **merges.text** file  which is not part of vocabulary or training dataset.

à ¤

à ¥

Ġ à¤

à¤ ¾

Below is the code used for training

```
from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer

filename= "marathi.txt"

# Initialize a tokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()


# Customize training
tokenizer.train(files=filename, vocab_size=20_000, min_frequency=3, special_tokens=[
    "<s>",
    "<pad>",
    "</s>",
    "<unk>",
    "<mask>",
])
```

I also tried setting ByteLevelBPETokenizer's unicode_normalizer parameter by setting each of the values to ['nfc', 'nfd', 'nfkc', 'nfkd'].

How do I get correct words in vocabulary, how to handle it?

Comment: You might want to tokenize by symbol.

Comment: when its trained on english text , I get desirable output..
I think it has to do with utf-8 encoding of text while in `tokenizer.train`  function call

Comment: Correct. Your text contains diacritics. You need to make sure the tokens are not split at the base letter and the diacritic mark. Then, I think, it will be enough. Another suggestion is to use SentencePiece tokenizer that is language agnostic and usually performs well on any kind of text.